# Code Composer Studio + Energia + CC3200 LAUNCHPAD - Energia Sketch Build Errors

Tags: energia

I have a CC3200 LAUNCHPAD and I saw the Code Composer Studio + Energia integration and thought it was sweet. From the tutorials, it looked like it was super easy to use an Energia Sketch in Code Composer. I can import a sketch just fine and I've imported the simple WifiWebClient sketch to try out my environment. When I import the sketch, it also makes a "lpcc3200_core" folder in the tree. When I go to build, that "lpcc3200_core" has errors which are all header file inclusions. The header files that it says are missing are clearly in the project already. I've posted on the TI E2E forum, the Energia forum, and contacted the Energia people directly with no luck. I figured I'd post this here.

**EDIT: I messed around with library locations before so here is clean run of the error.**

```
fatal error: cc_types.h: No such file or directory
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the actual compiler error (the first one)?

Comment: @EugeneSh, I added an image with the error message.

Comment: Your include files are in R:/Downloads... directory, but the compiler search the file on C: directory. It looks like a linking error. Add the R:/Downloads/... directory on your settings

Comment: I see that the file is included differently in both cases. Once with `<>` and once with `""`. Anyway, try prepending them with `driverlib/`

Comment: Could you please include the errors (and the like) as plain text, so people can search on them in the future?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I did a fresh run of the example without changing '<>' and running everything from the C: drive.

Comment: Can you manually locate the file and it's path?

Comment: @Passerby, the funny thing is, I can highlight the .h file name in the #include, right click the "open dependency", and it opens the file. I tried to explicitly add it to the root of the directory as well. No luck.

Comment: But is the file at the path that the compiler says it should be? Energía might find it bit not gcc

Answer (score 1):

After extensive forum posting, it turns out that Energia 16 and Code Composer Studio v6.1 are not compatible. I rolled back to Energia 15 and all is fine with the world again.